# Verificar threads do C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, thread, multithreading

Estou tentando entender o código abaixo, porém sem sucesso.
Pelo que pesquisei, o `GetMaxThreads` retorna o máximo de threads disponíveis e `GetAvailableThreads` o que tem disponível. No caso da saída abaixo, não existe mais threads disponíveis? O que o .Net C# faz nesta situação?

```
int threads;
int disponiveis;
int dummy;
long consultas = Interlocked.Read(ref _threads);

ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out threads, out dummy);
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out disponiveis, out dummy);

_gerenciador.Log(String.Format("Status dos threads: Consultas {0}, Threads: {1}, Disponíveis: {2}", consultas, threads, disponiveis));
```

Saída:

```
Status dos threads: Consultas 2, Threads: 1023, Disponíveis: 1020
```

Comment: Como assim "não existe mais threads disponíveis""? A saida indica que há mais de 1000 threads disponíveis para a sua aplicação (1020).

Comment: É isto que estou perguntando. eu não entendi o código, por isto da pergunta.

Comment: O pool de threads tem 1023 threads no total. O seu programa está usando 2 deles, e há 1020 disponíveis para quando você colocar um trabalho na fila (via `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, por exemplo).

Comment: @carlosfigueira está certo, apenas uma pequena correção - o programa está usando 3 (a main thread conta como uma thread em uso.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A indicação de *threads* disponíveis não significa que estas *threads* foram, de fato, criadas.
O `ThreadPool` trabalha com um número máximo de *threads* (possível de ser configurado), o método `GetMaxThreads` retorna esse número, enquanto que o `GetAvailableThreads` retorna o número de *threads* disponíveis (Max - Em Uso).

Caso as *threads* se esgotem, o `ThreadPool` aguardará a finalização de alguma *thread* em uso, para reusá-la para o novo trabalho.

**Vale lembrar que mesmo que o `ThreadPool` esteja esgotado ainda é possível criar novas *threads* "na mão": *`new Thread(Metodo).Start()`***

Apenas os trechos de código que utilizam o `ThreadPool` é que não terão suas tarefas executadas imediatamente.